# Python - Appending to wrong list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

In my script, I noticed something unusual: Values resulting from a for loop are being appended to a list other than the specified list.

```
def evaluateAddress(target_list,output_list):

        for target in target_list:
            result=callAddress(target) 
            transaction_targets=analyseTransaction(result,target)
            for i in transaction_targets:
                compileAddresses(output_list,i) 
    
        return output_list
```

The functions callAddress and analyseTransactions are not really relevant to this problem but can be provided if needed.
The fuction compileAddresses essentially appends values to a list:

```
def compileAddresses(compiled_receiver_addresses,input_addr): 
    try:
        compiled_receiver_addresses.append(input_addr)
        return compiled_receiver_addresses

    except:
        print('Failed to compile')
```

When executing the script, the target_list keeps growing, with every execution of the loop even if in my opinion it should be static. Only the output_list should grow with every loop execution.

What did I do wrong that might trigger this bug? I am happy to provide further context of the script.

Below there is the minimum reproducable example thanks to @MaKanU

```
def evaluateAddress(target_list,output_list):

        for target in target_list:
            result=target
            transaction_targets=[target + 1, target + 2]
            for i in transaction_targets:
                compileAddresses(output_list,i) 
    
        return output_list
        
def compileAddresses(compiled_receiver_addresses,input_addr): 
    try:
        compiled_receiver_addresses.append(input_addr)
        return compiled_receiver_addresses

    except:
        print('Failed to compile')
        
t = range(5)
        
out = evaluateAddress(t, list())

print(list(t))
print(out)
```

which results in

```
t: [0 1 2 3 4]
out: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

Comment: How are you defining the lists before sending them into `evaluateAddress`?

Comment: there are a lot of undefined functions and variables in your example. as such, it's very difficult to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: @MatsLindh that is the strange thing- I have not defined target_list before at all..

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. The only way `target_list` will grow in this code is if you pass the *same* list for both arguments to `evaluateAddress`.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the hint! I have added the full script so that it is reproducible

Comment: There really isn't anything that grows here; the issue is that you're appending two values for each iteration in `for target in target_list:` - so it's no surprise that there are two values being added to `output_list` for each invocation. (`for i in transaction_targets:` runs twice and appends a value each time, giving the result you're seeing)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a copy/view Problem. Since you call your function `compileAddresses` inside your function `evaluateAddress`, the list `output_list` is always the same list at the same memory location.

I replaced your missing function by some simple range lists to get a working example:

```py
def evaluateAddress(target_list,output_list):

        for target in target_list:
            result=target
            transaction_targets=[target + 1, target + 2]
            for i in transaction_targets:
                compileAddresses(output_list,i) 
    
        return output_list
        
def compileAddresses(compiled_receiver_addresses,input_addr): 
    try:
        compiled_receiver_addresses.append(input_addr)
        return compiled_receiver_addresses

    except:
        print('Failed to compile')
        
t = range(5)
        
out = evaluateAddress(t, list())

print(list(t))
print(out)
```

which results in

```
t: [0 1 2 3 4]
out: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

So your list are always called as a reference if you want multiple output list with different results you need to make a copy of your whichone you want append.

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful! I have added the MRE up in the original post and will also try to implement your suggestions!